# MySQL complex average

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to come up with a MySQL script for averaging Price in the following data, by
Price_Start_Date, but taking into consideration past prices that are *still valid* and taking the *latest price for each Id*.

Better explained with this example:

```
UUID, Size, Price_Start_Date, Id, Price
'b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288', '1.00', '1900-01-01', '7128311000001100', '783'
'b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288', '1.00', '1900-01-01', '7128711000001101', '1010'
'b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288', '1.00', '1900-01-01', '7129611000001101', '1147'
'b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288', '1.00', '2019-05-01', '7063411000001102', '1007'
'b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288', '1.00', '2023-04-01', '7063411000001102', '1032'
```

Line 4 should not be considered when averaging for 2023-04-01.
Result should be:

```
b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288    1.00    1900-01-01   980
b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288    1.00    2019-05-01   986.76
b2c944f4-a7b9-11ed-afbe-024291230288    1.00    2023-04-01   993
```

Tried different solutions but can't find a working one.
Can someone help with this?

Closest solution so far, but this does not take take into consideration  the *latest price for each Id*:

```
select distinct uuid, size, price_start_date, (
    select avg(price)
    from t1 u
    where u.uuid = a.uuid
    and u.size = a.size
    and u.price_start_date <= a.price_start_date
) as Price
FROM t1 a;
```

Comment: Please show what you tried and we'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you from scratch.

Comment: Wouldn't the last row be `993` (`783+1010+1147+1032)/4` ?

Comment: If you're using 8.x I think you can do this using window functions. If not, use a self-join that gets all rows whose `Price_Start_Date` is `<=` the date for each row.

Comment: @Bramar sorry, I added the closest I got so far

Comment: @Equinox, you are right, I corrected it

Comment: Why shouldn't line 4 be considered for 2023-04-01?

Comment: @Bramar because the price for Id 7063411000001102 was changed to 1032, and so, only 1032 should be taken into consideration when averaging for 2023-04-01. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs to do this, the following script seems to work properly, (0 values will not be included in averages):

```
SELECT DISTINCT uuid, size, price_start_date, (
    SELECT AVG(p2.price)
    FROM t1 p2
    WHERE p2.uuid = p1.uuid
    AND p2.size = p1.size
    AND p2.price != 0
    AND p2.price_start_date in (
        SELECT DISTINCT price_start_date
        FROM (
            SELECT
                price_start_date,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY price_start_date DESC) AS _rn
            FROM t1 p3
            WHERE p3.price_start_date <= p1.price_start_date
        ) sq
        WHERE _rn = 1
    )
) AS price
FROM t1 p1
ORDER BY price_start_date;
```

Answer (score -1):

> taking the latest price for each Id

That's your starting point. There's multiple ways of doing this - before MySQL had sub-selects there was the max concat trick, there's still [a whole page in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) on the problem.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM example a
JOIN (
  SELECT uuid, MAX(Price_Start_Date)
  FROM example b
  GROUP BY uuid
) AS b
ON a.uuid=b.uuid
AND a.Price_Start_Date=b.Price_Start_Date
;
```

But since you did not tell us how the table was structured, there is a risk of there being more than 1 record for a given uuid and Price_Start_Date hence....

```
SELECT price_start_date, AVG(aprice)
FROM (
  SELECT a.uuid, a.price_start_date, MAX(a.price) AS aprice
  FROM example a
  JOIN (
    SELECT uuid, MAX(Price_Start_Date)
    FROM example b
    GROUP BY uuid
  ) AS b
  ON a.uuid=b.uuid
  AND a.Price_Start_Date=b.Price_Start_Date
  GROUP BY uuid, price_start_date
) AS c
GROUP BY price_start_date
```

Which is *what you asked for*. However I cannot imagine how the output of the query makes any sense in the real world.